# Make a POST Request to Amazon Lex from NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-lex

I have created a bot using Amazon Lex, Now I want to call the PostText API provided by Amazon Lex : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html
using my NodeJS code.

I am using the following guide:
https://virtualbrakeman.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/aws-rest-api-authentication-using-node-js/

The only difference in mine is a POST request.

What should be the 'payload' value in my case ?

I am getting the error : 403 Forbidden when I make the POST request, but I am able to run the same API using Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in case of POST request the payload value should be as follows:
'{"inputText":" -- value_of_inputText -- "}'

One can also skip the whole calculation for creating headers and simply use [npm aws-sdk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk)

Comment: Can you solve this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72715776/audio-response-in-amazon-lex