# How can I play an audioStream returned by the Amazon Lex SDK when recognising an utterance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a chatbot with Amazon Lex with a Node.js Rest API using the [official docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lex-runtime-v2).

I'm sending a `RecognizeUtteranceCommand` & receiving an `audioStream` in the response.

How can I play this `audioStream`?

There's no examples in the documentation about playing the audio stream.

My code:

```js
const { LexRuntimeV2Client, RecognizeUtteranceCommand} = require("@aws-sdk/client-lex-runtime-v2");
const client = new LexRuntimeV2Client({ region: 'us-east-1' });


getResponse = async () => {
        const lexparams =
    {
        "botAliasId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "botId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
        "localeId": "en_US",
        "inputStream": <blob XX XX XX ....>,
        "requestContentType": "audio/x-l16; sample-rate=16000; channel-count=1",
        "sessionId": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "responseContentType": "audio/mpeg"
    }

    const command = new RecognizeUtteranceCommand  (lexparams);
    const response = await client.send(command);
    console.log(response);
}

getResponse();
```

The response:

```json
"messages": [
    {
        "content": "How was the day ?",
        "contentType": "PlainText"
    }
    ],
audioStream: Http2Stream {
    id: 1,
    closed: false,
    destroyed: false,
    state: {
    state: 5,
    weight: 16,
    sumDependencyWeight: 0,
    localClose: 1,
    remoteClose: 0,
    localWindowSize: 65535
    },
    readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: [],
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    constructed: true,
    sync: true,
    needReadable: false,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    destroyed: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrainWriters: null,
    multiAwaitDrain: false,
    readingMore: true,
    dataEmitted: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null,
    [Symbol(kPaused)]: null
    },
    writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: true,
    needDrain: true,
    ending: true,
    ended: true,
    finished: true,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: false,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    afterWriteTickInfo: null,
    buffered: [],
    bufferedIndex: 0,
    allBuffers: true,
    allNoop: true,
    pendingcb: 0,
    constructed: true,
    prefinished: true,
    errorEmitted: false,
    emitClose: true,
    autoDestroy: false,
    errored: null,
    closed: false,
    closeEmitted: false,
    [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defined as part of the [`RecognizeUtteranceCommandOutput`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-lex-runtime-v2/interfaces/recognizeutterancecommandoutput.html#audiostream) interface, `audioStream` is of type:

> `Readable` | [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream) | `Blob`

In other words, you ultimately have a **stream of byte data** in the `audio/mpeg` format.

It is up to you how to consume this stream, but for playing this audio on the client's device, I would:

1. Return `response.audioStream` back from the endpoint
2. Create a `Uint8Array` from the audio stream & subsequently, a `Blob` instance with the MIME type of `audio/mpeg`
3. URL encode the Blob instance and attach it to the `src` attribute of a HTML [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) element
4. Call the `.play()` method on the audio element

This should work:

```js
var stream = new Uint8Array(audioStream);
var audioBlob = new Blob([stream], { type: 'audio/mpeg' });
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
var objectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);

audioElement.src = objectUrl;
audioElement.play();
```

Comment: Do you see audioStream in my response? Is that how it will be?

Comment: Is that is in correct form to be converted to Blob ?

Comment: Yes. Audio not playing

Comment: No audio playing. Check this https://ibb.co/br0ZSn9

Comment: Same as I showed in my response above bro. https://ibb.co/Nm5bmmx

Comment: Any idea why it not coming ?

Comment: Thanks, brother. Adding `new Uint8Array(audioStream);` before converting to URL works.